# Remove duplicate substring from comma seperated string in php

Tags: php, string, duplicates, substring

I have this string: `$entitlemnet = '43857403,erot,43857403,erot,rejh'`

I want to remove all the duplicate values from this string. How can i do that?

See code below.

```
$roql_Ent_result = RNCPHP\ROQL::query($EntQuery)->next();

while ($Ent_result = $roql_Ent_result->next())
{
    $Entitlement = $Ent_result['Entitlement'];
    $findme = $Entitlement.",";
    $pos = stripos($EntitlementString, $findme);

    if ($pos === false)
    {
        $EntitlementString = $EntitlementString.$Entitlement.", "; 
    }
}

if ($EntitlementString != "")
{
    $EntitlementString = substr($EntitlementString,0,(strlen($EntitlementString)-2)).";";
}
```

Comment: do you mean this string `43857403,erot,43857403,erot,rejh` will result to `43857403,erot,rejh` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$entitlemnet = "43857403,erot,43857403,erot,rejh";
$result = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $entitlemnet)));
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to remove the duplicates from the string.

```
$entitlemnet = '43857403,erot,43857403,erot,rejh';
$unique_string = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $entitlemnet)));
```

1. Turn your string into an array by splitting it with explode() by
   delimiter ','
2. Remove duplicate values with the function array_unique()
3. Turn the array back into a string by concatenating the array values with
       delimiter ','

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
$entitlemnet = "43857403,erot,43857403,erot,rejh";
$result = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $entitlemnet)));
echo $result;
```

Will result in:

> 43857403,erot,rejh

Comment: Thank you so much, this code is working fine, But if their is a space in the starting like 'STOR-APD, 001-0669-001,ISSP3.0,CXFS7,STOR-SAN,STOR-CXFS, STOR-DMF, STOR-TMF, 001-0586-030, DMF6,STOR-DMF,001-0669-001, XFS-XVM6, XFS-XVM-RHEL6,STOR-XVM, STOR-NAS, 001-9007-001, STOR-LUSTRE' its not  deleting duplicates.

Comment: @hemanthkumar
You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). 
`$result = implode(',', array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(',', $entitlemnet))));`